# Программно спровоцировать событие нажатия JButton

Tags: java, swing, awt, handlers

Имеется кнопка JButton applyButton с обработчиком события ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED. Необходимо программно создать это событие.

Рабочий способ:

```
ActionEvent actionEvent = new ActionEvent(applayButton, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
for (ActionListener listener : applyButton.getActionListeners()){
    listener.actionPerformed(actionEvent);
}
```

А это способ, который по моим представлениям должен работать, однако не работает:

```
applyButton.dispatchEvent(new ActionEvent(applayButton, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
```

Почему не работает второй способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может достаточно вызвать [doClick()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick())?

```
applyButton.addActionListener((ActionListener) e -> {
    // do smth
});
applyButton.doClick();
```